# Shellcode not running, despite disabling stack protections

Tags: c, shellcode

I am exploring shellcode.  I wrote an example program as part of my exploration.
Using objdump, I got the following shellcode:

```
\xb8\x0a\x00\x00\x00\xc
```

for the simple function:

```
int boo()
{
    return(10);
}
```

I then wrote the following program to attempt to run the shellcode:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

unsigned char code[] = "\xb8\x0a\x00\x00\x00\xc3";  

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  int foo_value = 0;

  int (*foo)() = (int(*)())code;
  foo_value = foo();

  printf("%d\n", foo_value);
}
```

I am compiling using gcc, with the options:

```
-fno-stack-protector -z execstack
```

However, when I attempt to run, I still get a segfault.

What am I messing up?

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/1385241/how-to-disable-nx-on-linux

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there!

You have placed your `code[]` outside of main, it's a global array. Global variables are not placed on the stack. They can be placed:

- In the BSS section if there are not initialized
- In the data section if there are initialized and access in both
  read/write
- In the rodata section if there are only accessed in read

Let's verify this You can use `readelf` command to check all the sections of your binary (I only show the ones we are interested in):

```
$ readelf -S --wide <your binary>
There are 31 section headers, starting at offset 0x39c0:

Section Headers:
  [Nr] Name              Type            Address          Off    Size   ES Flg Lk Inf Al
[...]
  [16] .text             PROGBITS        0000000000001060 001060 0001a5 00  AX  0   0 16
[...]
  [18] .rodata           PROGBITS        0000000000002000 002000 000008 00   
[...]
  [25] .data             PROGBITS        0000000000004000 003000 000017 00  WA  0   0  8
[...]
  [26] .bss              NOBITS          0000000000004017 003017 000001 00  WA  0   0  1
```

Then we can look for your symbol `code` in your binary:

```
$ readelf -s <your binary> | grep code
    66: 0000000000004010     7 OBJECT  GLOBAL DEFAULT   25 code
```

This confirms that your variable/array `code` is in `.data` section, which doesn't present the `X` flag, so you cannot execute code from it.

From there, the solution is obvious, place your array in your main function:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  uint8_t code[] = "\xb8\x0a\x00\x00\x00\xc3";  
  int foo_value = 0;
  
  int (*foo)() = (int(*)())code;
  foo_value = foo();

  printf("%d\n", foo_value);
}
```

**However, this may also not work!**

Your C compiler may find that yes, you are using `code`, but never reading from it anything, so it will optimize it and simply allocate it on the stack without initializing it. This is what happens with my version of GCC.

To force the compiler to **not** optimize the array, use `volatile` keyword.

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  volatile uint8_t code[] = "\xb8\x0a\x00\x00\x00\xc3";  
  int foo_value = 0;

  int (*foo)() = (int(*)())code;
  foo_value = foo();

  printf("%d\n", foo_value);
}
```

In a real use-case, your array would be allocated on the stack and sent as a parameter to another function which itself would modify the array content with shellcode. So you wouldn't encounter such compiler optimization issue.

Comment: It is still seg faulting.  It does give me a message that it is failing, this time (instead of simply returning -1073741819).

Comment: @joosooph I am not sure to understand what you mean by "It does give me amessage that it is failing", do you mean the "Segmentation fault" message?
Which compiler are you using? Which OS?
Can you check the generated assembly code for your main function? (thanks to `objdump`)

Comment: I am using Windows 10.  I compiled the function boo() using GCC on RHEL, just to be able to run objdump on it.
I am using the GCC compiler that comes with CodeBlocks.2
It complains about the -fno-stack-protector -z execstack line if I try on linux.

Comment: Neeeeeevermind.  Got it sorted.  Windows is a bit of a different deal.
Finally got past the issues with gcc not recognizing some of the compiler arguments.  
This works on linux, at least.  
Thank you for your help!!!

Comment: @joosooph No problem, thanks for coming back with the final result!